# MYSQL backup options using mysqldump and mysqlbackup

Tags: mysql, mysql-backup

I'm currently using `mysqldump` to backup mysql database.

I heard that `mysqlbackup` offers a much much better performance.  Unfortunately it requires MySQL enterprise version which is pricy.

A few questions:

1. Does a database backed up by `mysqlbackup` require the user to have MySQL Enterprise Subscription to restore it?
2. Are there any free or low cost alternatives that offer better performance than `mysqldump`?